# NancyFX and IPv6 issues

Tags: c#, ssl, ipv6, nancy

I have a client-server application that works using a https connection with a self signed certificate and a Nancy Selfhost server.

After installing the application i run the following scripts to prepeare the server.

- Add SSL Certificate to store
- Check witch ip:ports are configured with *netsh http show sslcert*
- Remove all registrations with port number 4443 (only if they are found with previous step):

  - *netsh http del sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443*
  - *netsh http del sslcert ipport=[::]:4443*
  - *netsh http del urlacl url=https://+:4443/*
- And then add url reservation with: *netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:4443/ user=everyone*
- Add SSL Certicates with:

  - *netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443 certhash=XXX appid={XXX}*
  - *netsh http add sslcert ipport=[::]:4443 certhash=XXX appid={XXX}*

Then I start the server. The code for starting the self host server is:

```
public void Start(string baseUrl) {
        string url = baseUrl;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        var uris = new[]
                {
                    new Uri($"{uri.Scheme}://localhost:{uri.Port}"),
                };
        server = new NancyHost(new CustomBootstrapper(url, Api1, Api2, applicationConfiguration), uris);            
        server.Start();
    }
```

In this code is the *baseURL* the Hostname of the machine.

The client server connection works in most cases, but one situation it doesn't. This is when i try to run the the server on a specific computer. It has the following differences from other servers:

- Windows 8
- Pinging the hostname of this returns a IPv6 adress.

When starting the client application, it gives the following error: 
*The underlying connection was closed: Could not establsh trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel*

Now i'm stuck, because I am not sure why it would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had some old certification registrations and url reservations still active. After clearing them all, the issue was resolved.